# Como compartir coneccion jdni de BD en java

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

Tenia el siguiente error, no podia agregar la misma dependencia de BD a mis proyectos, pero no obtube respuesta de la comunidad, entonces decidi a poster la solucion.

Error

JBAS014803: Duplicate resource

org.jboss.msc.service.duplicateserviceexception: jdni is already registered

Answer (score 0):

Entonces modifique la clase de coneccion.

@Resource
private SessionContext context;

```
@Produces
@ConnectionBD
public EntityManager em() {
    //String jndiName = "java:global/jdni/PostgresSqlModel";
    EntityManager manager = null;//(EntityManager) context.lookup(jndiName);
    
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SystemDataBaseDS");
    manager = emf.createEntityManager();
    return manager;
}
```

Despues de esto no tuve probleams, aunque antes se tiene que borrar la siguiente linea en el persistence.xml

property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name"
value="java:global/jdni/PostgresSqlModel"

Y por debe tener su configuracion de DS en su stanalone.xml de sus servidor.